# How to place a div outside of a wrapper class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$ (document). ready (function () { 
    var x = -((window.innerWidth -1024)/2)+"px"; 
    Alert (x); 
    $ ('. home labels'). css ('left','x'); 
});
```

I am getting the alert value. But is not able to set this value to left. Please anyone help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('.home labels').css('left',x);
```

`'x'` is `string` not the `variable` you have defined

`x` is a `variable` but `'x'` is a `string`